# Having trouble to make Ref working using Kleisli for dependency injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'm trying to do dependency injection with Kleisli (ReaderT) but I don't seam to be doing it right. I'm adding items to a map wrapped inside a Ref and when I list the values after calling the add method the map seams to be empty. Can anyone give me some hints? What am I doing wrong here?

```
import cats.data.ReaderT
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}

object KleisliQuestion extends IOApp {
  case class Item(id: String, name: String)

  trait Context {
    val service: ReaderT[IO, Context, Service]
  }

  trait Service {
    def add(item: Item): ReaderT[IO, Context, Unit]
    def list: ReaderT[IO, Context, Iterable[Item]]
  }

  object MyService extends Service {
    private val refIO = Ref[IO].of(Map[String, Item]())

    def add(item: Item): ReaderT[IO, Context, Unit] = ReaderT.liftF(
      refIO.flatMap(ref => ref.update(_ + (item.id -> item)))
    )

    def list: ReaderT[IO, Context, Iterable[Item]] = ReaderT.liftF(refIO.flatMap(ref =>
      ref.get.map(m => m.values)))
  }

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val context = new Context {
      override val service: ReaderT[IO, Context, Service] =
        ReaderT[IO, Context, Service] { _ => IO(MyService)}
    }
    val program = for {
      context <- ReaderT.ask[IO, Context]
      service <- context.service
      - <- service.add(Item("1", "Something 1"))
      - <- service.add(Item("2", "Something 2"))
      - <- service.add(Item("3", "Something 3"))
      list <- service.list
    } yield list
    program.run(context).map(it => it.map{item =>
      println(item)
      item
    }) *> IO(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

Comment: Here: `refIO.flatMap(ref => ...)` you are creating a new empty ref every time; thus no update at the end. - Why are you even using `Kliesli` for dependency injection? That is a bad idea; why not just keep things simple like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/EhjT9cWUSh2C5nRusAMf8Q/3) - Let me guess, you are new to all this, right? I would recommend you to join the [**Typelevel** **discord** server](https://discord.gg/yyjXBYmc) and ask your question there, most of those folks do not check SO regularly.

Comment: Yes indeed. New to all this and trying to learn as fast as I can Thanks a lot for your references.

Comment: Okey, check this comment of mine of **Reddit** that I made for someone in a similar situation: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/rlgq9n/comment/hpfqb8t/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 Especially point 1, read the _"Programs as Values"_ series, that is the core of all this. The second advice is to keep things simple, `Kliesli` for dependency injection is just a misleading idea of what FP is, nothing as simple as passing parameters to methods / classes.

Comment: I got that idea from [here](https://softwaremill.com/reader-monad-constructor-dependency-injection-friend-or-foe) and plenty of more references including one of Daniel Ciocîrlan videos. I could not find any reference to the Reader Monad without mentioning dependency injection. So my question is, why "Kliesli for dependency injection is just a misleading idea of what FP is"?

Comment: So, first I would like to correct myself, it should have been: _"`Kliesli` for dependency injection is just a misleading idea of what FP is in **Scala**"_ - Second, as you can see, the very same blog post you share mentions that replacing constructor based DI with `Reader` or `Kliesli` is not really always the best idea, they are complementary and if you ask me, in the example shown I don't see any point in using `Kliesli` just ask for the `EmailServer` as another argument of the method. Third, my point is just: be pragmatic - Anyways, as I said, this is easier to cover in **Discord**.